# Node- Unable to require in an module.export

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with a RabbitMQ connection and exporting the channel after creating the same to import it in the routes file in my nodejs code.

But for some reason, it is `undefined` when imported in the `routes.js` file.

#### Export

```js
let connection;
let channel;

const connect = async () => {
  try {
    const amqpServer = 'amqp://localhost:5672';
    connection = await amqp.connect(amqpServer);
    channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue('product');
    console.log('Product service connected to RABBITMQ');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
connect();

module.exports.connection = connection;
module.exports.channel = channel;
```

#### routes.js

```js
const { channel } = require('./index');
console.log(channel) //  undefined
```

Idk what is it that I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

CommonJS `require` is synchronous so you should write something like this:

### Export

```
const connect = async () => {
  try {
    const amqpServer = 'amqp://localhost:5672';
    const connection = await amqp.connect(amqpServer);
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue('product');
    console.log('Product service connected to RABBITMQ');
    return [connection, channel];
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

module.exports = connect();
```

### routes.js

```
const [connection, channel] = await require('./index');
console.log(channel) //  defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
let connection;
let channel;

const connect = async () => {
  try {
    const amqpServer = 'amqp://localhost:5672';
    connection = await amqp.connect(amqpServer);
    channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue('product');
    console.log('Product service connected to RABBITMQ');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
connect();

exports.connection = connection;
exports.channel = channel;
```